# iptables extended modules give invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, kernel, iptables

I installed an iptables modules to match Modbus protocol, compilation ran well, I integreted the .ko module with command insmod, and now when I type iptables -m modbus so every thing is good until now, but when I tried to execute an iptables filtre, it doesn't work

```
aa@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m modbus --unitid  11
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
aa@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
[ 3692.909462] ip_tables: modbus match: invalid size 0 != 40
```

I think it's a problem in the match function of my code, I checked, but I couldn't figure the problem, i just verified the TCP header of my packet in the MATCH:

```
/* 
Triggers when a packet comes in matching the register match 
*/

static int match(const struct sk_buff *skb,
      const struct net_device *in,
      const struct net_device *out,
      const void *matchinfo,int offset,
      const void *hdr, u_int16_t datalen,
      int *hotdrop)
{

  const struct iphdr *iph;
  const struct tcphdr *tcph;
  u_int8_t tcplen;

  /* Examine the TCP header, which is 32 bytes after the IP
     header.  "hdr" points to just after IP header */
  const struct modbus_tcp *modbus;
  const struct ipt_modbus *modbusinfo = matchinfo;
  const struct modbus_data *data;

  iph = ip_hdr(skb);

  tcph = (void *)iph + iph->ihl*4;

  /* TCP header length caluculation*/
  tcplen = tcph->doff*4;

  /* Match our structure to the data part */
  modbus = hdr+tcplen;

  /* If length is less then the total of IP and TCP header, that
     should be part of three way handshake .. allow it */
  if (ntohs(iph->tot_len) == 20+tcplen) {
    if(modbusinfo->allow_tcp == 1)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }

  else
    {

  /* Return the "OR"s of all the parameters given.  If any
     of the given parameters is true, the whole thing is true */       

      return (func_code_check(modbusinfo->funccode_flags,(modbus->modbus_d).func_code, modbusinfo->func_code[0],modbusinfo->func_code[1], modbusinfo->invflags_funccode) || unitid_check(modbusinfo->unitid_flags,(modbus->modbus_d).unit_id, modbusinfo->unit_id,modbusinfo->invflags_unitid) || refnum_check(modbusinfo->refnum_flags,(modbus->modbus_d).ref_num, modbusinfo->ref_num,modbusinfo->invflags_refnum) || length_check(modbusinfo->length_flags,(modbus->modbus_h).length, modbusinfo->length[0],modbusinfo->length[1], modbusinfo->invflags_length));

    }
}
```

Comment: what's your code to register the match module? it is not a problem with this function.

Comment: just a simple insmod xt_modbus.ko

Comment: this is the code from wich i copied the function:  https://github.com/stevenylai/ralink_sdk/blob/5d3729a93e1f722c658d29606347c35816cd0ec8/source/linux-2.4.x/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c

Comment: no, I mean, in the kernel module, how did you register this match? like the code xt_register_match(...) or something?

Comment: xt_register_match(&modbus_match);

Comment: what's the kernel version?